# What should be the return type when writing Linq query for selecting specific columns?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using ObjectDataSourse to bind data to GridView. I have written following function to show specific columns on grid view.
Program doesn't throw any error but it doesn't show anything on grid.
What is the problem?

```
 public IEnumerable<object> selectSpecificColumn()
 {
     IEnumerable<object> productTab = (from p in context.Products
                                       select new{ p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.OrderDate } );
     return productTab;        
 }
```

Comment: How do you set the binding in your GridView?

Comment: are you sure the issue is because of **selectSpecificColumn** method only ?

Comment: I am only using ObjectDataSourse. When I tried to select all columns with return type IEnumerable<Product> it runs well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options am going to suggest you. It's your choice to pick one.

- Use `Product` class as it is and hide the columns which you don't want.
- Create a new class with required properties.
- Create a datatable out of it and return it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I have tried these ways successfully but I am new in Linq so just want to return function using Linq.

Comment: You can't return, even if you do am not sure that data-binding will support that. All what you can do is just copy paste the code where you need to bind the data(I won't suggest it, it is a bad idea). Also note that anonymous types are meant to use it in local variables only not to return it from a method

Comment: I think you are right.Because when I put debug on linq expression, it generates right select query but grid view shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer the `poco class` in this scenario

```
public class Product
{
   public Int32 ProductID {get; set;}
   public String ProductName {get; set;}
   //add more as needed
}

public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> selectSpecificColumn()
{
     IEnumerable<Product> productTab = from p in context.Products select new Product({ProductID  =p.ProductID, ProductName = p.ProductName});
     return productTab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind to a defined class, the binding knows what properties the class has to bind to. The problem you're having is that you're creating anonymous type in your LINQ code. And then you're assigning the result to a list of objects `IEnumerable<object>`. Now the binding tries to bind to this list of objects and does not know what properties the objects have to bind to.

I know that there are times when we have to need to encapsulate our LINQ in a separate function especially if it will be called from several locations. However, with the current framework specifications, the function cannot return an anonymous type. If you do not want to return the entire Products class, you will have to create a new class.